# Transformation Law for a scalar field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, field-theory, lorentz-symmetry

The following is taken from Peskin and Schroeder page 36:

$$\partial_{\mu}\phi(x) \rightarrow \partial_{\mu}(\phi(\Lambda^{-1}x)) = (\Lambda^{-1})^{\nu}_{\mu}(\partial_{\nu}\phi)(\Lambda^{-1}x)$$

It describes the transformation law for a scalar field $\phi(x)$ for an active transformation.

I would like to work out the intermediate steps by myself as they are missing from the textbook. Can you please correct any mistakes I make?

$$\partial_{\mu}\phi(x) \rightarrow \partial_{\mu}(\phi(\Lambda^{-1}x)) = \frac{\partial(\phi(\Lambda^{-1}x))}{\partial x^{\mu}} = \frac{\partial (\Lambda^{-1}x)^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\mu}} \frac{\partial \phi((\Lambda^{-1}x))}{\partial (\Lambda^{-1}x)^{\nu}}  = (\Lambda^{-1})^{\nu}_{\mu}(\partial_{\nu}\phi)(\Lambda^{-1}x).$$

Am I correct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a "check my work" question.